# jQuery find closest button and trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Darkroom JS](https://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/) to crop / manipulate images on the fly. However, I need the canvas to be saved (Via the floppy disk in the toolbar) before I process the image as base64.

I thought I would try it with JQuery and target the particular element, However Darkroom doesn't give the toolbar items a specific class.

So I'm looking at finding it via jQuery closest or similar and then triggering the click.

The HTML that Darkoom Produces is as follows :

```
<div class="darkroom-container">
  <div class="darkroom-toolbar">
    <div class="darkroom-button-group">
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-default" disabled="">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#undo"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-default" disabled="">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#redo"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="darkroom-button-group">
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-default">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#rotate-left"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-default">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#rotate-right"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="darkroom-button-group">
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-default darkroom-button-active">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#crop"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-success">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#done"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-danger">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#close"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="darkroom-button-group">
      <button type="button" class="darkroom-button darkroom-button-default">
      <svg class="darkroom-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#save"/>
      </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="darkroom-image-container">
    <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 556px; height: 556px; position: relative; -moz-user-select: none;">
      <canvas class="lower-canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 556px; height: 556px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;" width="556" height="556"></canvas>
      <canvas class="upper-canvas " style="position: absolute; width: 556px; height: 556px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: crosshair;" width="556" height="556"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="darkroom-source-container" style="display: none;">
    <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; position: relative; -moz-user-select: none;">
      <canvas class="lower-canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
      <canvas class="upper-canvas " style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can get into the 4th button group using :

```
var button_group = $('.darkroom-button-group').eq(3);
```

But I am struggling to trigger the button.

My current jQuery is as follows :

```
    var button_group = $('.darkroom-button-group').eq(3);

    button_group.closest('.darkroom-button').trigger('click');
```

Comment: share your html also, from the description it looks like `button_group.find('.darkroom-button').first().trigger('click');`

Comment: Welcome on SO... What about relevant HTML?!

Comment: 'For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree' -[jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)   
Most important is that it traverses up through its ancestors. You probably want to go down as @ArunPJohny sugests

Comment: Bizzare, The HTML was showing in the editor / message. Try again!

Comment: Can you provide a Jsfiddle preview? I'm not sure that its well explained

Comment: https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs/blob/master/lib/js/plugins/darkroom.save.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest will search for the parent elements. In your case, you need to search for the child elements. for that you can use `.find()`. Then your code will be,

```
button_group.find('.darkroom-button:first').trigger('click');
```

This will trigger the jquery click handler.

If you dont have the click event handler, then you can try the DOM click,

```
button_group.find('.darkroom-button')[0].click()
```

Comment: @StuBlackett there are multiple buttons in each groups. Which button you want to trigger?

Comment: I'm trying to target the button with SVG : <use xlink:href="#save"/>

Comment: @StuBlackett is your HTML exactly the same as in the OP?? if so then this above code must work..

Comment: did you create any jquery click event handler for that button?

Comment: No, that was all built by the library. @Reddy I suspect its the library not allowing a trigger, as I can add a class to the button using Anoops' Code

Comment: try with DOM click button_group.find('.darkroom-button')[0].click().

Comment: @StuBlackett what do you expect to happen if you trigger a click? also what happens now when you manually click that button?

Comment: @StuBlackett try this `button_group.find('.darkroom-button')[0].click()`

Comment: Hi @AnoopJoshi that worked a treat the DOM Click method, thank you!!

Comment: @Reddy the first one will trigger the jquery click event handler. 2nd one will emulate the button click itself(like a person clicks on the button).

Comment: @StuBlackett then you can accept it as answer right?

Comment: Sure can! Cheers @AnoopJoshi

Answer (score 0):

i think u can get button now just filter attribute of button 
and then

```
$("attribute ").closest('.darkroom-button').trigger('click');
```